# Default print settings on iOS

Tags: ios, airprint

Is there a way to set default print settings on iOS? Whenever I print, I want to print double-sided and black and white with compatible printers. However, the print dialog forgets my last setting and keeps switching back to single-sided and color.

Is there a way to set the default settings to be double-sided and black and white?